# Need to save One to many relationship VB6

Tags: arrays, sorting, vb6

So I have to save from a grid where there are two types of IDs. LineId & CustId. There can be multiple CustIds for each LineId. An example of data would be like this:

```
LineId     CustId
1          33
2          98
7          101
1          51
3          28
7          02
1          35
```

I need to save the code with a save procedure that accepts a null-delimited string of CustIds for each Line id. I call the save procedure once for each LineId being saved. I cannot change how the save procedure works.

So far I have been adding the grids to a type array with line id and cust id.

```
Dim typeRows(gridRows - 1) As Ids 'gridRows is rowcount of grid
For i = 0 To grid.Rows - 1
    typeRows(i).LineId = grid.TextMatrix(i, GridColumns.colLineId)
    typeRows(i).CustId = grid.TextMatrix(i, GridColumns.colCustId)
Next
```

But I'm a little stuck on what I should do next. Should I sort the grid? Then how would I go through the sorted grid and combine cust ids for each lineid?

Any help or guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't see your problem, as long as the data from the row stays on the same row, you just get both vales from the rows.

Comment: create an array (size gridrows) of null-delimited strings, sort the list, loop through the list, as long as the lineid stays the same add custid to the null-delimited string, when lineid changes create a new null-delimited string and increase an counter to keep track how many null-delimited strings are in use .. after the loop is done save all null-delimited strings which are in use (loop till the counter value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without sorting the grid you have to loop through the array as well to check if the id was already found before, that can be done as well, but might take some time depending on the size of your data

```
'1 form with :
'    1 flexgrid control : name=grid
Option Explicit

Private Type Ids
  LineId As String
  CustId As String
End Type

Private Sub Form_Click()
  'export to delimited string
  Dim intRow As Integer
  Dim intId As Integer
  Dim intBound As Integer
  Dim udtIds() As Ids
  Dim blnThere As Boolean
  Dim intCount As Integer
  With grid
    intBound = .Rows - 1
    ReDim udtIds(intBound) As Ids
    intCount = 0
    For intRow = 1 To intBound
      'loop through all rows
      blnThere = False
      For intId = 0 To intBound
        'check if lineid was already found before
        If udtIds(intId).LineId = .TextMatrix(intRow, 0) Then
          blnThere = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next intId
      If blnThere Then
        'if lineid was already found before, just add the custid
        udtIds(intId).CustId = udtIds(intId).CustId & "," & .TextMatrix(intRow, 1)
      Else
        'if lineid is new, then create new lineid with custid in udt
        udtIds(intCount).LineId = .TextMatrix(intRow, 0)
        udtIds(intCount).CustId = .TextMatrix(intRow, 1)
        intCount = intCount + 1
      End If
    Next intRow
  End With 'grid
  'now you can save the udt
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With grid
    'fill grid with example values
    .Cols = 2
    .Rows = 8
    .FixedRows = 1
    .FixedCols = 0
    .TextMatrix(0, 0) = "LineId"
    .TextMatrix(0, 1) = "CustId"
    .TextMatrix(1, 0) = "1"
    .TextMatrix(2, 0) = "2"
    .TextMatrix(3, 0) = "7"
    .TextMatrix(4, 0) = "1"
    .TextMatrix(5, 0) = "3"
    .TextMatrix(6, 0) = "7"
    .TextMatrix(7, 0) = "1"
    .TextMatrix(1, 1) = "33"
    .TextMatrix(2, 1) = "98"
    .TextMatrix(3, 1) = "101"
    .TextMatrix(4, 1) = "51"
    .TextMatrix(5, 1) = "28"
    .TextMatrix(6, 1) = "02"
    .TextMatrix(7, 1) = "35"
  End With 'grid
End Sub
```